# How can I make flex-items block elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The Flex-box spec [3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/) states that flex-items are not block containers:

> A flex item establishes a new formatting context for its contents. The
>   type of this formatting context is determined by its ‘display’ value,
>   as usual. The computed ‘display’ of a flex item is determined by
>   applying the table in CSS 2.1 Chapter 9.7. However, flex items are
>   flex-level boxes, not block-level boxes: they participate in their
>   container's flex formatting context, not in a block formatting
>   context.

Look at this small example (fiddle: [4](http://jsfiddle.net/dfrWd/2/)):

```
#flex {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    background-color: red;
}
#flexAuto {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    flex: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
#oneHundredPercent {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="flex">
    <div id="flexAuto">
        <div id="oneHundredPercent"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would expect #oneHundredPercent to be 200px high, like the size of its container #flexAuto. But it's 0px high. The actual output looks like the left picture. I would expect the right picture:

[image: actual][image: expected]

Is there a simple way to make the flex-item behave like a box again?

Comment: Why would you expect the output to be the right picture (50% red on top, 50% green on the bottom)?  The outer element is 200px tall.  Its child has a height of auto, and the innermost element has a height of 100%.  The only possible outcomes would be 100% red or 100% green.  Change the display type of the outermost element back to block and you'll see it has nothing to do with Flexbox.

Comment: You are right, I didn't expect the picture on the right. I changed the question and forgot to update the image. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the child of the outer flex box is normally a flex item until you change it's display mode to block.

So you just need to state a height for FlexAuto explicitly (`height:100%`). The height will be computed relatively to the Flexbox container.

And then the innermost element will display as you intended.

(By the way, even if flexAuto were still a flex item, you might have needed to set flex:"stretch" perhaps.)

http://jsfiddle.net/dfrWd/6/

Comment: Of course, setting the height of #flexAuto to a value will work, but then I don't really need flexbox anymore. This will also behave widely different if there are more children then just flexAuto (e.g. a div  with height 30px) present

Comment: can't find "flex: stretch" in the spec, what do you mean?

Comment: When you use display box, it is not a flex item any longer so it won't behave as a flex item (hmmh Im writting tautologies lol). That's the reason you have to set a height. Now I am not sure how you would mix block level elements and flex items but I tend to think that if it comes to that, there must be something wrong with the layout. Basically you should be able to go the flex route all the way.

As far as Flex stretch is concerned.. I meant the align-item / align-content of the spec... but it's the behaviour by default so you can ignore that.

Comment: I am not mixing flex and non-flex items. I just have some flex-items with heights and some without

Comment: Ok. Then you don't really have to use display box. Your #flexAuto should use "display: flex" to make it a flexbox. Or at the very least, display box should be deleted but then #onehundredpercent is not a flex item until its parent is made a flexbox. As per your current code, only #flex is a flex item.

PS: just to avoid confusions : "flex:auto" will not turn an element into a flex item/box.

Comment: Don't want to sound rude, but you seem to got the terminology totally wrong. Check out the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#flex-containers): #flex is a **flex-container** and #flexAuto is a **flex-item**

Comment: #flex is a flexbox (or flex 'container' box if you will) and #flexauto is a flexitem until you change the display value to something other than flex. It's the display option that counts. Paragraph 4 of the spec you quoted. I was sloppy with my comment above. display: block should be erased. and only #flex is a flex container box when #flexAuto should be made into one too.